# TextView's width, wrap dynamically into ImageView's width

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I'd like my textview to auto adjust whatever the width of the imageview. I want to attain the image below. **Basically the same image and text** but different orientation. These are grids of images. I am just resuing the layout. How do I handle this? thanks

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <!--  android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"-->

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/content_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="Desc"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnItemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:alpha=".7"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="Order" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Update:**

I included a background: `android:background="#00000000"` just to show that the textview's width should fit to the imageview's. The text should overlay to the top of the image. I am using Universal-Image-Loader, and I think it is difficult to get the image size since it is being downloaded from the *background*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have TextView overlaid over ImageView you can have your layout like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/parl" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imgView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/imgView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="textView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your example sir but it didn't overlay to the image. It is just located at the bottom.

Comment: Ok. As I understand, you want to align the textview based on the imageview's width. If so, this would be a lot more easier, with the code and not in the xml file. Get the ImageViews width using getwidth and set it to Textview using setWidth. Pls ignore my XML file. I didnt know that it had to overlay.

Comment: I updated my question, you have a point but I am using Universal-Image-Loader, and download the images in background, so the textview may get a null pointer as to the size, since the image is still being downlaoded.

Comment: Till your image is downloaded, I pressume you will have a dummy loader image. Set the width of textview to this dummy images. Once your download is complete, change the textview width again based on the downloaded image.

Comment: I got your point, I tried that but image is still not overlay at the bottom of the image, but instead at the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Relative Layout and give the attributes of imageview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Hi how are you" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Those images represents one image and text, such it is in different orientation. Can you show a more complete example sir. thanks

Comment: in the same image u have text below the image ?

Comment: if you dont want text to strech use 9 patch and select the area to be streched

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonok"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:text="OK" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:text="Hi how are you" />

</RelativeLayout>
```